# Cannot drag and drop object in xcode 9.2

Tags: swift, xcode, viewcontroller

I am using xcode 9.2 and one day I can't drag and drop all the things like below objects. 
Does anyone know what is the problem about that. thanks.

[image: Object List 1]

I would like to use below object. 
[image: Object List 2]

Comment: Xcode 9??? Hard to help, it’s years out of date.

Comment: because my macbook using older version and it only support xcode 9.2

Comment: But you can't use it for anything; you can never submit an app to the App Store with it, so what good is it?

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of troubleshooting thoughts:

- Restart Xcode
- Are you able to drag and it just doesn't "take" in the storyboard? If so, double check that you're dropping it in a view controller that can accept the object